# How to forward traffic to specific url in google cloud run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a live app running on Google Cloud Run.

I have a bug in my app that I want to troubleshoot through VSCODE by adding breakpoints through Debugger.

I am using ngrok.io to expose my localhost. So now I want to route all my traffic that hit the google cloud run should be forwarded to my ngrok.io url so that I could receive that request in my local server that would be debugged very easily.

Is this possible in Google Cloud Run ?
I would really appreciate for any contribution here.

Thanks
Regards
Ayyaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only Cloud Run, you can't achieve that. If you use a Load Balancer in front of Cloud Run, it's possible to change the backend to route the traffic elsewhere than to Cloud Run.

You can also run your container locally and play the requests that you want on it. You can find the request in the Cloud Run logs, and resend them to your local environment and debug your code.